# Issue in creating executable jar for SWT/Jface Application

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, production-environment

**Problem:** I have created a Desktop Application with Java and SWT/JFace. 
 The project contains design, action, util and model classes. Created executable jar, All works fine but now i am facing some branding and endorsing issue i.e.

```
 - Minimize should display in task bar.
 - Running executable jar is showing as a javaw.exe in task manager list
   not with its name.
 - On alt + tab application appear as unknown exe
```

Now I want a suggestion. Can these issue be solved easily without impacting a lot if yes then please provide needed clue? or should I go to Eclipse RCP plugin productization which can handle all above means.

If sole answer is No, Then please suggest an optimize way to migrate to eclipse RCP. it would be nice if you point action list as I am new in such productization.

**Update** As i have created GUI by SWT/Jface and, using main as entry point I have created its executable jar, is this creating problem that i hav mentioned above?

Comment: Converting to a Eclipse RCP is a substantial change, too large to cover in an answer here. An Eclipse RCP will look more like a 'normal' app on most platforms.

Comment: Calling `Display.setAppName("name")` **before** creating the `Display` may help with the app name.

Comment: @greg-449 yeah you are right...I am also stick as My application is not so big as it will overkill the use of Eclipse RCP.

Comment: An [Eclipse e4 RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) need not be too large.

Comment: @greg-449 Display.setAppName("name") is not working I have extend the dialog class to creat my front end dialog. is this the reason?

Comment: @greg-449 any help to pin the application in Window task bar?

Comment: Sorry, I am a Mac user these days

Comment: @greg-449 Display.setAppName("name") is still not working for task manage-> process(task list). it is showing javaw.exe as its name.

Comment: @greg-449 Display.setAppName("Display Manager");
 Display display = new Display();
 Shell shell = new Shell(display);

Comment: Reason was, I have created my form by extending Dialog class, and Dialog dont appear in Task bar, all are fixed now the open question is why my exe is not showing its name in task list of task manager. it is appearing as javaw.exe and i want to appear as all exe appear measn with there name.